# Is it possible to map a path in OSX?

Tags: macos

I am using VMware share folder fonction:

so i have the path `/Volume/VMware Shared Folder/DevFolder/`

Is it possible to map this path to be able to access the same folder using

```
cd /DevFolder
```

**I try :**

```
sudo ln -f -s /Volume/VMware Shared Folder/DevFolder/ /dev_folder
```

then

```
cd /dev_folder
-> No such file or directory
```

**And**

```
sudo ln -f -s /Volume/VMware Shared Folder/DevFolder/ /Users/nassimus/Desktop/dev
```

it create an icon on the desktop, but when i click on it shows : `The original item 'Dev' cant be found`

Comment: just make a symlink - `sudo ln -s "/Volume/VMWare Shared Folder/DevFolder" /DevFolder` should to the needed

Comment: i try it, ls show the new foler, but when i use cd /DevFolder it say : No such File or Directroy

Comment: The path is supposed to be `/Volumes/VMWare Shared Folders` - so while my comment is related to your original question; you probably want `sudo ln -f -s "/Volumes/VMWare Shared Folders/DevFolder" /DevFolder` (the `-f` is to remove the previously created erroneous link)

Comment: i think you misunderstand my need, i dont need a shortlink to my folder, i want to be able to do cd /dev_folder instead of the cd /Volume/VMware Share...

Comment: Why is this questions tagged [tag:linux]? I see nothing about Linux in the body of the question.

Comment: many osx commands are inherited from linux

Comment: No they aren't. Where did you get that idea?

Comment: OSX is based on unix system

Comment: OSX inherits the Mach kernel which was used by NeXT, userland tools mostly from FreeBSD, and a UI slightly based on OS9 but developed in-house at Apple. Nothing about Linux there.

Comment: @NassimMOUALEK symlinks are the best way of getting a similar behaviour to a secondary mount point without having to actually mount anything.

Comment: OK but its not working for me i give it many tries

Comment: maybe the failed is related to VMware Shared Folder Function

Comment: "not working" is insufficient debugging info for a diagnosis to be made. If you tried something, please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35223948/edit) to include your attempt, along with the result (be it an error or something else). Also, be aware that StackOverflow is a *programming* resource, where we help folks having problems with their source code. Your question is more about general computing, probably better suited to http://SuperUser.com/.

Comment: ok i edit my question

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://unix.stackexchange.com ? (But it looks like a typo to me - `/Volume/...` should be `/Volumes/...`, no ? Also you need to escape the spaces in the path.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems - you have typos in the path (`/Volume` should be `/Volumes` and `Folder` should be `Folders`), and you also need to escape the spaces:

```
sudo ln -fs /Volumes/VMware\ Shared\ Folders/DevFolder/ /dev_folder
                   ^       ^       ^       ^
```

Comment: done, thank you very mutch